# How send notification to groups using SignalR in Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

Here we are using asp.net core singnalR alpha2 version. How to send notification for groups (group of users)? If any sample is there for scenario, post here the sample link.

In Hub write method with group.

```
public class SignalRCommonHub : Hub
{
   
    public void SendToGroup(int groupId, int userId)
    {
        Clients.Group(groupId.ToString()).InvokeAsync("refresh", groupId, userId);
    }
}
```

In controller called the hub method.

```
private readonly IHubContext<SignalRCommonHub> isignalRhub;

public SignalRModel(IHubContext<SignalRCommonHub> signalRhub)
{
    this.isignalRhub = signalRhub;
}

public void RefreshPage(int groupId, int userId)
{
    this.isignalRhub.Clients.Group(groupId.ToString()).InvokeAsync("refresh", groupId, userId);
}
```

In client side not trigger when call method in client side.

User online status update based on groups (group of users) using signalR sample available means post here link. Suggest idea for how to implement the user online status.

Thanks,

Comment: Please add some information on what you have tried, the basics of the code you are using and the how you intend to specify groups.

Comment: Please take some time to clean up your question and format the code.

Answer (score 1):

from your front end interface, you will need to setup the hub/connection, then make a call to Add/Remove groups using the connectionId and the group id/name.

eg:  `await _viewerHubContext.Groups.AddAsync(connectionId, groupName);`

Then when you broadcast calls, you just use the group id/name and signalR will send to those groups.

eg: `return Clients.Group(groupName).InvokeAsync("Send", "SendData", data);`